# Deploying an application using Java Web Start

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-poi, noclassdeffounderror, java-web-start

I recently developed a whole system in Java that connects to a database (using `jtds.jdbc.Driver`) and exports and imports the table content to an excel sheet using Apache POI. I used Swing for the user interface. The user will interact with it for authentication and file management.

Apparently the client wants it deployed so I started to deploy using Java Web Start on an Apache tomcat server.

I put in reference [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-web-start-jnlp-tutorial-unofficial-guide/comment-page-1/#comment-126081) interesting tutorial. Since I followed it

### Launch file

```xml
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:8080/" href="Test.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>Talisman</title>
    <vendor>CCT</vendor>
    <homepage href="http://localhost:8080/"/>
    <description>Testing Testing</description>
  </information>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+"/>
    <jar href="Talisman.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <application-desc main-class="cct.karim.karim"/>
</jnlp>
```

### Run-time exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2685)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1620)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 9 more
```

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You're not including your POI jar with your deployment. I suspect there'll be other jars that you need to deploy too. Everything your app needs has to be downloaded and installed on your client's host.

You'll need a line like:

```
   <jar href="apache-poi.x.y.jar"/>
```

for each jar file.

Comment: well i did this <jar href="poi-3.9-20121203.jar"/> and I got this com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: http://localhost:8080/poi-3.9-20121203.jar

Comment: I used a lot of Jars in in my project then I exported my project into a jar(Talisman.jar)

Comment: Since the codebase points to `http://localhost:8080/`, check the location of each Jar in the browser using something like.. `http://localhost:8080/poi-3.9-20121203.jar`  If ***you*** cannot download it directly in the browser, neither can the JRE.

Comment: all my jars are internal jars inside the project direcotry